# How to ensure that I use the latest Promise()

Tags: javascript, promise

Here are three tags. Click tag to send asynchronous request. I assign the returned value to variable `tagResult`.

Asynchronous request is implemented by Promise(). When I click tag quickly, I don't want the value returned by the previous asynchronous request. I just want the result of the last asynchronous request.

Fake code：

```js
let tagResult = '';

// When click the tag, it will fetch the tag result
function fetchTagResult(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ajax(params).then(res => resolve(res))
    })
}
```

Suppose tag1 tag2 tag3, return 1, 2, 3 respectively

If I quickly click tag1 tag2 tag3, I just want tagresult to be assigned to 3, NEVER assigned 1, 2!

---

**update question: Fri Jan 03 2020 22:58:09 GMT+0800**

Thanks for helping me solve my problem!
I may not have described clearly, the core of the problem is how to solve the problem of asynchronous requests, not function throttling.
Thanks again!

Comment: Did you try with a `setTimeout` debounce? This way you could trigger the async work after a delay, and get only the last one.

Comment: Promises are not cancellable. You can use observables from `RxJS` to achieve what you want. See: https://itnext.io/javascript-promises-vs-rxjs-observables-de5309583ca2#77f3

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I may not have described clearly, the core of the problem is how to solve the problem of asynchronous requests, not function throttling... Thanks again! @soywod

Comment: @Jenkey2011 — My answer (of three hours ago) covers that.

Comment: Thanks @HarunYilmaz . It looks good! But it might be too heavy for me ~

Answer (score 3):

Store the value clicked in a shared variable. When the request resolves, compare it to the stored value. Reject the promise if the last click doesn't match the one for the current promise.

```
const fetchTagResult = (function () {
  // IIFE for scope

  let last_clicked = null;

  function fetchTagResult(params, clicked) {
      last_clicked = clicked;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          ajax(params).then(result => {
              if (clicked === last_clicked) {
                  resolve(result);
              } else {
                  reject();
              }
          })
      });
  }

  return fetchTagResult;

})();
```

This could be rewritten to avoid the nested promise antipattern, and use async/await to tidy it up in general.

```
const fetchTagResult = (function () {
  // IIFE for scope

  let last_clicked = null;

  async function fetchTagResult(params, clicked) {
      last_clicked = clicked;
      const result = await ajax(params);
      if (clicked === last_clicked) {
          return result;
      }
      throw new Error("Something else was clicked in the meantime");
  }

  return fetchTagResult;

})();
```